# The component is locked (impossible to edit) in 05C mode

Tags: 2011, siteedit

I have a problem with 2011 version. There are few components marked with a little lock and I can´t figure out how to unlock it. I am afraid that it was locked by a person, who is no longer in my company.

[image: printscreen]

I need to edit the content of these components at 05C. I have tried to use the "check-out" and "undo check-out" buttons, but nothing really changed.

How can I unlock it?

Comment: You'll probably need a user with Administration privileges to unlock the component through the CME. Failing that, they can be checked-in via the Core Service API.

Comment: I think the file is opened by some user. When an item is opened by a user it shows lock icon.

Comment: I changed "folders" to "components," which I'm pretty sure is what you meant.

Comment: Also consider voting for this idea to give certain non-admins some ability to check-in items they don't own: http://ideas.sdltridion.com/ideas/detail.asp?i=1587.

Answer (score 10):

Open the item and check the "Locked by" section on the Info tab. 
Then contact that person.

If it's a system account, the item is likely locked by workflow and needs to go through the workflow process to unlock.

If it's locked by a person who no longer works there, you'll need a Tridion Administrator to unlock the item for you.

Answer (score -2):

You can do the same using database query if you have acsess to tridion CM database

```
update ITEM_REFERENCE_PUBLICATIONS set ITEM_LOCK=0,ITEM_LOCK_DATE=null,ITEM_LOCK_OWNER=null    where ITEM_LOCK=1  and ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=19882
```

Comment: Executing queries directly on the DB is not supported.

Comment: That is true that running Queries directly on DB is not Supported. But sometimes you don't have option other than this. Here we are talking in terms of a developer not a Content Editor, So I think one should know all the ways of to resolve a problem.